# Standard Submit button submits form, Bootstrap V3 Button won't submit form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have two form on a page.  One for uploading images, and the other for another purpose.

If I use a standard submit button the form submits just fine, but if I switch it to a Twitter Bootsrap button, with the same name and id as the standard button, it doesn't submit the form.  I have some JQuery that changes the appearance of the button, but I have eliminated that code, and it still doesn't work.

```
   PHP Code
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //upload functions
}

   JQuery Code
//Show Instructions When File Is Selected
    $("#file").on('change', function(e) {
               var uploadButton = $('#UploadImage');
               $(uploadButton).removeClass('btn-default');
               $(uploadButton).addClass('btn-upload');
               $("#uploadImageHolder").addClass('alert alert-danger');  
                $('#uploadStatus').html('');
                $('#uploadInstruct').html('<span><img src="../images/redarrow.png">PLEASE CLICK RED BUTTON TO UPLOAD THIS IMAGE</span>');
                $('#initMessage').html('');
                });
    //Show the Loading Screen When Upload Form Is Sent

    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        $("#uploadSuccess").remove();
        $("#uploadImageHolder").remove();
        $.fancybox(
            '<p  class="text-center"><img src="../images/loading.gif" width="48px" height="48px"></p><p class="text-center">Please Wait While Your Image Is Processed</p>',
            {
                'modal'             : true,
                'overlayColor'      : '#000000',
                'width'             : 350,
                'height'            : 'auto',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });
    });

 <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form" id="myForm">
<div class="form-group">
<p>
    <label for="file">File input</label>
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file">
</p>
<input name="NextImageID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $NextImageID; ?>">
<p id="uploadImageHolder">
    <button type="submit" id="UploadImage" name="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span>Upload Image</span></button><span id='uploadInstruct'></span>
</p>
</div>                      
</form>
```

I have searched high and low and can't seem to figure out what is going on.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You're removing (essentially deleting) the button upon the `submit` event.  Why not just `hide()` instead of `remove()`?  I'm not sure if it will make any difference but perhaps it's a timing issue.  Also `action=""` will not do anything when you submit... you'll need an `action` URL if you're not doing `ajax`.

Comment: The form was being submitted to the same page, but I added the page URL.  Made no difference.

I don't think I am removing the button before the submit.  The elements that are being removed are simply text elements.

If I just make it a standard form submit button, it submits just fine.  I need to style it, to dumb the form down so the user knows what to do next.

Comment: The element being removed,`#uploadImageHolder` is the container holding your button... so it's really not just a _"text element"_.  When you remove the container, you also remove its content.  Otherwise, none of this is making any sense.  Change your `remove()` into `hide()`, for nothing else, so you can rule it out.

Comment: I see what you were saying, just realized what it was doing.  I removed

`$("#uploadImageHolder").remove();`

altogether but still didn't submit the form.  I also changed the button type to "button" instead of "submit", but that didn't seem to make any difference either.

Comment: Makes no sense at all.  Construct two jsFiddle demos... one with the working version and another with this broken version, so we can do additional troubleshooting.

Comment: Using a `type="button"` would break a working form, unless you `submit()` by capturing the click with jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using your JavaScript console to check for JavaScript errors?

Comment: Changed the button back to a "submit", also id and name to "submit", and changed the .remove() command to .hide().  Simply changing the .remove() to .hide() didn't change things, but when I changed the type, id and name to "submit" it appears to be working.  Sort of strange.  How do I accept your comments as the answer?  Sort of a newbie at this.

Comment: I'd have to post my comments as an answer below (stand by while I figure that out).  However, what you describe makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.  The `name` and `id` are not required and should have no bearing on operation.  The only way to know what is really going on would be to inspect the dynamic changes to the DOM using your browser's tools.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could change button type to a normal button.

In #UploadImage.click you could call form submit action like this:

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});
```

Also, form action is empty, which is the post url ?

Comment: `$("#UploadImage").click(function() {
        $("#uploadSuccess").remove();
  $("#uploadImageHolder").remove();
  $("#myForm" ).submit();
  $.fancybox(
   '<p  class="text-center"><img src="../images/loading.gif" width="48px" height="48px"></p><p class="text-center">Please Wait While Your Image Is Processed</p>',
   {
    'modal'    : true,
    'overlayColor'  : '#000000',
    'width'          : 350,
    'height'         : 'auto',
    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
    'transitionOut'  : 'none'
   });
  
 });`

New JQuery code, still no submit.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know what is really going on would be to inspect the dynamic DOM changes using your browser's DOM inspection tools.

However, the bare minimum HTML markup for a form submission is as follows...

```
<form action="yoururl">
    ....
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```